As of V0.103687, is there a Minor Prophecy for getting each of Selene's Hexes?
https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Fated_List_of_Minor_Prophecies/Hades_II
Lists this as one of the starting Prophecies. Does it still exist or has it been removed? I'm not seeing it in V0.103687?

Gifts of the Moon
The daughter of the god of the dead shall harness each of Selene's Hexes.


Yes, it works like the other boon-givers, offer her 2 Nectar for the prophecy display to unlock.
